# C++ seekg to ignore a part of a file?

Tags: c++, stream, seekg

I have a very simple question in C++.
What is the equivalent of

```
x = new char[length];
mystream.read(x, length*sizeof(char));
delete[] x;
```

with `seekg` to ignore a part of size `length` of a binary file ?

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `seekg`, just use [`istream::ignore`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore).

---

If you insist on using `seekg`, the way to go is `seekg(length, std::ios::cur)`.

Comment: `seekg` is presumably much more efficient than `ignore`

Comment: @Robᵩ Do you have any reference for that?

Comment: @Rodrigo - nope, just a presumption on my part. YMMV